# Basic JS object {a:1,b:2} not supported in Nashorn?

Tags: javascript, java, java-8, nashorn

I was a bit surprised when raising an exception with this simple expression in Nashorn (JDK8 from Oracle, latest) :

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
engine.eval("{a:1,b:2}");
```

Which gives

> javax.script.ScriptException: :1:6 Expected ; but found :
>   {a:1,b:2};
>         ^ in  at line number 1 at column number 6     at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:470)
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.compileImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:537)
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.compileImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:524)
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:402)
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:155)
>     at
>   javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this functionality is similar to javascript `eval`, you're getting this error because `eval("{a:1,b:2}")` evaluates `{}` as a code block and not as an object literal.

```js
eval("{a:1,b:2}")
```

That code is equivalent to:

```
{
  a: 1,
  b: 2
}
```

The error is being thrown in the `b: 2` line. Here, `a` becomes a [**labeled statement**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) within a new `{}` block. So, if you had created an object literal with just one property, this would've worked.

```js
eval("{a:1}") // no errors
```

If you want an object literal, then assign it to a variable

```
eval("var obj = {a:1,b:2}")
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Yes, all that reamrks are true. My real use case was to evaluate this code to build a Map with keys a and b and values (resp.) 1 and 2... Which seems complicated without hacking with an intermedaite variable like eval("var obj = {a:1,b:2}")

Comment: @richetyann How are you planning on using the created object literal? To use that object, you need to assign it to some variable. I've explained that in the answer, `eval("{a:1,b:2}")` creates labeled statement. Not object literals.

Comment: Not really, in fact I can use the evaluated object as a Map after calling ((ScriptObjectMirror) o).to(Map.class)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to adiga, using

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
engine.eval("({a:1,b:2})");
```

solved my problem. (Note the parenthesis which disable the "code block")